# `R(r+'(?=[>,]|$)','g')` is converted to `R('^'+r+'+01943df1-b949-454b-b253-e39f9f31ca1e)','g')`

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

Today I found something weird with stack snippets...

I found it in this question:[Interpreting Fish (no, not that Fish)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48649/interpreting-fish-no-not-that-fish)

It was in my answer: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/48686/14732

Basically, `R(r+'(?=[>,]|$)','g')` is being converted to `R('^'+r+'+01943df1-b949-454b-b253-e39f9f31ca1e)','g')`.

Here it is converted to `+@@0@@)` when editing/writting the question.

You can check it here:

```js
var alert=console.log=function(s){document.write(s)+'<br>';};
try{
alert(prompt(R=RegExp,r='(<<?><|><>>?|,<\.\.>,|>><>|><<<>|<><<|<>>><)').match(R('^'+r+'+$'))[0].split(R(r+'(?=[>,]|$)','g')).join(' '));
}catch(e){console.log(e);}
```

I tried IE11 and Chrome, and both have the bug.